# C++ char arrays -- Why the garbage?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am trying to get only the alphabetic characters from an array of characters entered by the user. Here is a snippet:

```
const int SIZE(100);

int main()
{
    char* entryTextArray = new char[SIZE];
    char* adjustedTextArray= new char[SIZE];
    int i, j;

    cout << "Enter text, and I will tell you if it is a palindrome!" << endl;
    cin.get(entryTextArray, SIZE);

    cout << "Length of char array is " << strlen(entryTextArray) << endl;

    for(i=0, j=0; i <= (strlen(entryTextArray)); i++) {

        if(isalpha(entryTextArray[i]) && (entryTextArray[i] != '\0')) {

            adjustedTextArray[j] = entryTextArray[i];
            cout << adjustedTextArray[j] << endl;
            j++;

        }
    }
    cout << adjustedTextArray << endl;

}
```

When I compile, the cout of the adjustedTextArray displays the proper individual entrys, but the cout outside of the loop is the entry text, followed by garbage. I have no idea what is wrong! Help?!

Comment: There's a perfectly good `std::string` and `std::remove_if` you can make use of.

Comment: `adjustedTextArray` is not NUL-terminated. Right before printing it, do `adjustedTextArray[j] = 0`.

Comment: I should have close voted for _"Simple typographical error ..."_ rather.

Answer (score 3):

You have the condition:

```
if (something && (entryTextArray[i] != '\0'))
```

so you are explicitly avoiding to copy the NUL terminating value from `entryTextArray` to `adjustedTextArray`. So you need to place it manually.

But since you are working in C++ using `std::string` just makes more sense.